# Is it possible and how to get all the information on a corporation in Canada, BC

Tags: canada, business, british-columbia, construction-law

There is a super long story of how we ended up in this situation (in fact too long to describe here), but at the end of the day, one of the contractors who started doing renovations in our apartment caused a lot of damages and disappeared without even returning a deposit.

After many months, the insurance company decided not to pursue them and we are currently on our own on this case.

My question is, is it possible and how to get all the information regarding the subject company?
All I have right now is business number, corporation name, and potentially the address.
I want to figure out is:

1. who are all the owners, partners, etc...
2. What are their assets if any?

That is for the start.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a requirement for a general contractor to be licensed. However, you should see if your municipality requires a license.

You should also check whether they're a member of the [Canadian Home Builder's Association (CHBA)](http://chbabc.org/app2/membersearch/index.php/search) or registered with [BC Housing](https://www.bchousing.org/licensing-consumer-services/builder-licensing/).

You should also check the [Better Business Bureau of Mainland BC](https://www.bbb.org/local-bbb/bbb-of-mainland-b.c.).

Corporations do have to register, see [BC Registries and Online Services](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/governments/organizational-structure/ministries-organizations/ministries/citizens-services/bc-registries-online-services).

Comment: Do I have to go through a court to get that information? Or I can request for these details myself?